# CKEditor custom stylesSet overrides default

Tags: ckeditor

I'm testing adding custom stylesSet.  So in my code i add the following (per [instructions](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles) in)

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('custom_style', [
  { name: 'No UL Bullets', element: 'ul', styles: { 'list-style-type': 'none' } },
  { name: 'My Custom Inline', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'mine' } }
]);

oEditor.config.stylesSet = 'custom_style';
```

The problem is that it overrides the rest of the default styles that comes with CKEditor.  I cant seem to figure out how to just append my new styles with the existing once.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change `config.stylesSet` option to append your styles to default ones. You can edit the `styles.js` file, adding and removing styles from it. It is a configuration file just like `config.js`.

**Update**: You can set `config.stylesSet` directly to avoid loading `styles.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    stylesSet: [
        { name: 'Big',              element: 'big' },
        { name: 'Small',            element: 'small' },
        { name: 'Typewriter',       element: 'tt' }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, At first I was doing it this way but the reason why I moved it out and added it to my initializing code is because every time I updated ckeditor code I kept forgetting about those changes and end up over writting the code.  I'm ok with moving that code from styles.js to my code I just wanted to see if there was an alternative to it.

Comment: You can move that code to your files. `config.stylesSet` can be set directly. I'll update my answer.